Field extension $K/\Bbb{Q}$ of given $e,f,g$ .
Let $e,f,g$ be an fixed arbitrary positive integers.

I want to find an example of prime number $p$ and a degree $efg$
algebraic extension $K/\Bbb{Q}$ whose ramification index is
$e$,inertia degree is $f$, the number of primes above $p$ is $g$.

Let's start with local version.
An example of local field extension whose ramification index is $e$ and inertia degree is $f$ is , $L_{e,f}:=\Bbb{Q}_p(\mu_{p^e-1}, p^{1/f})/\Bbb{Q}_p$.
This is composition field of $\Bbb{Q}_p(\mu_{p^e-1})/\Bbb{Q}_p$ whose ramification index is $e$ and $\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/f})/\Bbb{Q}_p$ whose inertia degree is $f$.
If possible, I want to utilize this example. But it seems impossible to answer my titled question because prime above $p$ of $\Bbb{Q}(\mu_{p^e-1}, p^{1/f})/\Bbb{Q}$ may not take arbitrary value. Another idea is also welcomed.
Thank you for your help.

＠KCd Sorry for my poor English. This question is about a problem I've been thinking about for over three years, which I came up with myself. Since I haven't made any progress, I posted it hoping someone might give me a hint.

If $K = \mathbf Q(\alpha)$ and $\mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z[\alpha]$ (a "monogenic" number field, which includes all quadratic and cyclotomic fields), with $\alpha$ having minimal polynomial $h(x) \in \mathbf Z[x]$, the way $p$ factors in $\mathcal O_K$ matches how $h(x) \bmod p$ decomposes into irreducibles: if $h(x) \equiv \pi_1(x)^{e_1}\cdots \pi_g(x)^{e_g} \bmod p$ where the $\pi_i(x) \bmod p$ are distinct monic irreducibles, then
$p\mathcal O_K = \mathfrak p_1^{e_1}\cdots \mathfrak p_g^{e_g}$ where $f(\mathfrak p_i|p) = \deg \pi_i(x)$.  This also works without knowing whether or not $\mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z[\alpha]$: the condition $p \nmid [\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\alpha]]$ is enough to be sure that the way $h(x) \bmod p$ factors into irreducibles reflects how $p\mathcal O_K$ factors into prime ideals.
A way to check $p \nmid [\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\alpha]]$ without knowing $\mathcal O_K$ is by using Dedekind's index theorem: look here.
Your question can be answered in two steps: (i) find a monic irreducible polynomial $h(x)$ of degree $efg$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$ and a prime $p$ such that $h(x) \bmod p$ is a product of $g$ distinct monic irreducibles with multiplicity $e$ and common degree $f$ and (ii) check that $\mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z[\alpha]$, or at least that $p \nmid [\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\alpha]]$.  If $p \mid [\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\alpha]]$, use a different $h(x)$ and try again.
As long as there are at least $g$ monic irreducibles of degree $f$ in $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)[x]$, say $\pi_1(x), \ldots, \pi_g(x) \bmod p$,
you could try the following. Pick a prime $q \not= p$, such as either $2$ or $3$, and a monic irreducible $\pi(x) \bmod q$ of degree $efg$. Let $h(x) \in \mathbf Z[x]$ satisfy $h(x) \equiv \pi(x) \bmod q$ and $h(x) \equiv \pi_1(x)^e\cdots \pi_g(x)^e$.  The $h(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Q$ by the reduction mod $q$ test. Set $K = \mathbf Q(\alpha)$ where $h(\alpha) = 0$, so $[K:\mathbf Q] = \deg h = efg$. As long as $p \nmid [\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\alpha]]$ this example will fit your conditions.

Thank you very much. I am surprised that there was a solution to something I had been struggling with for over three years. I will report back here if I can construct an example based on your hint over the coming weeks.
